# Prevent users to not delete if not logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, crud

I am currently working with CRUD in identity. But I can crack this. I am trying, to make it so that you can ONLY delete if logged in.

I have tryed by adding `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` But that isn't working, it send me to login page AFTER you had entered the delete page. This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult _RemoveItems()
    {
        var Items = db.CreatePosts.ToList();

        return PartialView(Items);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _RemoveItem(int Id)
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        { 
            CreatePost CreatePost = db.CreatePosts.Find(Id);
            if (CreatePost != null)
            {
                db.CreatePosts.Remove(CreatePost);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
    }
```

And this is my delete

```
@Html.ActionLink("Slet", "_RemoveItem", "Home", new { @id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
```

What am i doing wrong, since i can't make it so you need to be logged in before you can enter the page `_RemoveItem`

Comment: If the link exists in your *view*, then it will give the impression that the option to delete is allowed if not logged in. From what you've posted, it doesn't look like they would have the ability to delete, but it would redirect them back to the index page with no explanation of what happened. I don't think you can prevent the user from going into the delete controller (without building a filter) but you can prevent them from executing the code contents of the action if they're not logged in, but the `Identity.IsUserAuthenticated` should do the trick.

Comment: The problem is that, it dosen't why? I don't know. I have proberly placed it wrong, but where it should be placed than, i don't know.

Comment: Just as an aside, your [HttpGet] method name is _RemoveItem while your [HttpPost] method name is _RemoveItems.

Comment: Shouldn't they both be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[Authorize]` attribute, in a line above your method:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult _RemoveItems()
```

This will require anyone accessing that method to be logged in, period.

You can also add more parameters to the Authorize attribute to manage what roles are allowed and so on.

As in:

```
[Authorize(Roles="SpecialRole, OtherRole")]
```

In this case, the method only allows users in the 'SpecialRole' role and/or the 'OtherRole' role, or in both roles to have access.

Comment: Tryed your [AUTHORIZE] and that "kinda" work. The problem is that it now, says this, whenn i try to delete. http://i.imgur.com/xTsz9KI.png

Comment: @Code King, I've commented on your original post about what can possibly be causing the exception.

Comment: Allright i made it work, why i got that error? I don't know, i deleted it all, and wrote it again, and than it worked! Placing the [Authorize], make it work! Thanks alot! Have a lovely day!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the delete button on your view to disappear, you're going to have to do some extra work to make that happen:

In the controller action that displays your view, you somehow need to pass if the user is signed in or not (you *could* do this in your view, but you shouldn't). You can do this easily with ViewBag or modify your model to include a property, whatever way suits you best.

```
[HttpGet] public void Index() {
    ViewBag.IsLoggedIn = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

In your view,

```
@(ViewBag.IsLoggedIn == false ? "" : Html.ActionLink("Slet", "_RemoveItem", "Home", new { @id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" }))
```

It *seems like you're already making sure they are logged in* and I made this answer since that is what you seemed like you wanted based on [my potential misunderstanding] of your comments.

Comment: But then the user could still type in the URL to remove so its not really safe. With [AUTHORIZE] you can block access to the resource / controller action if the user is not authenticated.

Comment: But that's it - he already is checking to see if they are authenticated. Unless the `[Authorize]` attribute and the property he's checking in the OP return different things, which I would think, should not happen.

Comment: Not what i am looking, for since that the users as Florian tells. Cann just write the url :)

Comment: So does `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` return `false` when a user is logged in?

Comment: If it does, then the answer with `[Authorize]` is the way to go. It should, however, return a 401 Unauthorized, so maybe the reason for the 404 is that the error page it is trying to redirect to does not exist.

Comment: If your mvc is configured correctly, the authorize should bring the user to the login page of your site to allow the user to log in to complete their action.